# How to compare the return value of WMIC by an IF condition?

Tags: windows, cmd, wmic

This is the console input/output:

```
C:\Users\>for /f "tokens=* skip=1" %a in ('wmic cpu get numberOfCores') do (set valor="%a")

" ) sers\> (set valor="4

" ) sers\> (set valor="

C:\Users\>set cpu=%valor:~6,-1%

C:\Users\>if "%cpu%" geq "4" (echo yes) else (echo no)
no
```

The loop seems to iterate twice, assigning the correct value (`4`) first and then overwriting it a blank value, thus clearing it, leading to a failed comparison with `4`.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this so that the condition returns `yes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to return the result, save it as a variable, then compare it.

You can allow the WMI Query Language to determine if the value is:

- Equal To `4`

```sh
wmic cpu where numberofcores^=4
wmic cpu where "numberofcores = 4"
```

- Greater Than `3`

```sh
wmic cpu where numberofcores^>3
wmic cpu where "numberofcores > 3"
```

Greater Than OR Equal To `4`.

```sh
wmic cpu where numberofcores^>^=4
wmic cpu where "numberofcores >= 4"
```

Putting those together into a format more akin to your posted intent:

```sh
wmic cpu where numberofcores^>3 get numberofcores /value 2>nul|find "NumberOfCores">nul&&(echo yes)||echo no
```

Or using more correct/robust, syntax:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe CPU Where "NumberOfCores >= 4" Get NumberOfCores /Value 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "NumberOfCores" 1>NUL && (Echo Yes) || Echo No
```